# Adobe Illustrator radial gradient is not smooth in both SVG and other image formats

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export, gradient

Adobe Illustrator gradients are not smooth.
I have tried to export in high resolution, and applying a blur effect to the gradient, but still it is not working.

Did I mess up some setting?

[image]

There seem to be circles in the gradient:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No you are doing nothing wrong, Illustrator does no dithering on gradients. Its to be expected 255 levels of color is not enough to make smooth graduations. You can hide this by adding very tiny amount of noise to the object, but then it gets rasterized.

Also most SVG and PDF rendering engines have the same problem